# What is the file path of a sd card when it is formatted as internal?

Tags: sd-card, internal-sd

I know that sd cards formatted as "portable" will be located in `/storage/sdcard<1,0>/` but where would a sd card be mounted or located when it is formatted as internal?

Answer (score 0):

It would be located in the `/mnt` partition under the `expand` folder.
For example mine is located:

> /mnt/expand/ee031623-1634-40d1-9f9f-902d68eceaee/